Vercel | Puppeteer Navigation failed because browser has disconnected
I’m trying to make a simple HTML to PDF API using Puppeteer but I keep getting this error message when sending a decent-sized HTML file. Nothing too crazy maybe a page or two. Here is the error and then here is my code.
Error:
Error generating PDF: Error: Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!

My Code
import { VercelRequest, VercelResponse } from '@vercel/node';
const puppeteer = require('autocode-puppeteer');

export default async function handler(req: VercelRequest, res: VercelResponse) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.status(405).send({ error: 'Only POST requests are allowed' });
        return;
    }

    console.log("Request body:", req.body);  // Log the entire request body
    const { html } = req.body;
    if (!html) {
        res.status(400).send({ error: 'No HTML content provided' });
        return;
    }
    console.log("HTML content:", html);  // Log the HTML content

    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: [, 'load', 'domcontentloaded', 'networkidle2'], timeout: 3000});
        const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });

        await browser.close();

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.status(200).send(pdf);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error generating PDF:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Failed to generate PDF');
    }
}


I have tried to let all the content load but still nothing. When i send in somthing like {"html": "<h1>This is a test</h1>"} i get the PDF back no problem but when i send more html that has CSS, i get this error.

I've never heard of autocode-puppeteer and it only has 6 stars on github. I would reach out to the person who made it or try something like browserless
